# How to convert string to int without skip first zeros's swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uint16

Note- I am not trying to convert hexttoInt Here ..
what i want to achieve is I have 9 digits of serial number 305419896(Decimal) in Hex format is 12345678.. I am just trying to take 0x1234 as one value and 0x5678 as other value..

My decimal number is 021340031 and in hex is 01459F7F and splitting into two strings like `"0145"` and `"9f7f"`.. I need this string value in format like 0x0145 , 0x9f7f..

In order to do that I am trying to convert Str to Int first.

```
 let firstValue = Int("0145")
```

then i am getting `145` only ..

Is there any way to convert String to UInt16 directly Or any work around to get the expected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to split your hex in half and display least significant two bytes, and most significant two bytes?

To do so, use bit mask and bit shift operators:

```
let a = 0x00045678

let first = (a >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF
let second = a & 0x0000FFFF

let firstString = String(format:"0x%04X", first)
let secondString = String(format:"0x%04X", second)
```

Output:

> 0x0004
>   0x5678

Format `0x%04X` will print a hex number of at least 4 digits, with leading zeroes if necessary

Comment: thanks i tried that with let a = 0x01459F7F but i am getting.."0x145" "0x9F7F" values is 0x145 and 0x0145 are same...? also i need it in Int not as string..any help

Comment: thnaks for that .. how can i get that string value in Int (I need same value though)..?

Comment: Yes, `0x0145` is the same value as `0x145`, leading zeroes can be ignored. If you want that as an `Int`, the variables `first` and `second` are what your are looking for - I just added Strings to show that they hold correct hex values

Comment: Thanks, well I need String values "0x145", "0x9F7F" but i need without quotes so that I can pass those directly ..any ideas..

Answer (score 0):

`UInt16` is not a base 16 `Int`, it is an `Int` that has 16 bits of storage.

What you want is `Int`'s little known initializer…

```
let firstValue = Int("0145" radix: 16)
```

That will give you the hex value for the string. However it will still remove any leading zero's as they have no value. There is no way to avoid this.

Note: You can use most any value for `radix` that you want and you can get strings from ints the same way if you need to convert back at some point.